# Number of odd digits in a list

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Consider the natural numbers from 1 to 2016 written in a list.  Determine the number of odd digits in this list.

e.g., in the list from 1 to 15 there are 14 odd digits.

I have tried placing preceding zeroes before the numbers and considering the total number of digits

Comment: what has been tried ?

Comment: what is your definition of an odd digit? I cannot find 11 odd digits in $\{1, \cdots, 15\}$

Comment: I'd argue that it depends on if you count 15 or 1 in the set, I just counted 12.

Comment: Sorry, there are actually 14 odd digits in the list (and yes you include 15 and 1 in the set).  I have tried placing preceding zeroes before the numbers and considering the total number of digits.

Comment: though I upvoted fonfonx's comment I realize they may be confusing last digit with digit. I also realize that I can't count to 14 apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $1$ to $999$ each odd digit will appear 100 times in the place of hundreds, 100 times in the place of tens and 100 times in the place of ones. To notice that just fix that digit and you have 100 choices for the rest two digits. Now deal the numbers from $1000$ to $1999$ the same, but account for the extra 1 at the beginning. Finally you can take care of the rest 17 numbers, which is quite easy.